# Command for timestamp without timezone in pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

How can I insert current timestamp without timezone in pgAdmin while inserting data manually?

I know that timestamp can be inserted using `now()` .
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) you can use `localtimestamp`  (instead of `current_timestamp` or `now()`)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP;
```